# Copying a branch of tree-like structured table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have the following table, where `ID` is the pk of the table and is `IDENTITY`

```
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+
| ID | ParentID | SomeValue |  FullPath   |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL     | A         | (1)         |
|  2 | 1        | A.1       | (1)/(2)     |
|  3 | 2        | A.1.1     | (1)/(2)/(3) |
|  4 | NULL     | B         | (4)         |
|  5 | 4        | B.1       | (4)/(5)     |
|  6 | 4        | B.2       | (4)/(6)     |
|  7 | 6        | B.2.1     | (4)/(6)/(7) |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

This table represents data stored in a [hierarchical way](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/archive/blogs/mvpawardprogram/hierarchies-convert-adjacency-list-to-nested-sets). I am creating a procedure that will take as input an `ID` and `new_ParentID` as parameters; ID (and its children and children's children, etc) will be the branch to copy into `new_ParentID`.

I started the procedure, but I cannot figure out how will I get the new ID of the parent I created in order to add it's children. For example, if I want to copy A.1 (and A.1.1) into B.2, once A.1-Copied will be created, I do not know its `ID` to put it as `ParentID` of A.1.1-Copied. I'm aware of the function `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but I don't know how to use it in a `CTE`. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
;WITH Branch
AS
(
    SELECT  ID,
            ParentGroupID,
            SomeValue
    FROM    
        #Table1 A
    WHERE
        ID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  E.ID,
            E.ParentGroupID,
            E.SomeValue
    FROM
        #Table1 E
    INNER JOIN Branch T
            ON  T.ID = E.ParentGroupID
) 
INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ParentGroupID IS NULL 
        THEN @new_ParentID
        ELSE ???,
    SomeValue + '-Copied'
FROM    
    Branch
```

How can I manage to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to correctly set the new parent of children of my copied branch ?

**EDITS:**

Suppose I want to copy branch with ID 4 (so the whole B branch) into ID 2 (so A.1 branch), we should have data as follows:

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| ID | ParentID | SomeValue  |       FullPath        |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | NULL     | A          | (1)                   |
|  2 | 1        | A.1        | (1)/(2)               |
|  3 | 2        | A.1.1      | (1)/(2)/(3)           |
|  4 | NULL     | B          | (4)                   |
|  5 | 4        | B.1        | (4)/(5)               |
|  6 | 4        | B.2        | (4)/(6)               |
|  7 | 6        | B.2.1      | (4)/(6)/(7)           |
|  8 | 2        | B-Copy     | (1)/(2)/(8)           |
|  9 | 8        | B.1-Copy   | (1)/(2)/(8)/(9)       |
| 10 | 8        | B.2-Copy   | (1)/(2)/(8)/(10)      |
| 11 | 10       | B.2.1-Copy | (1)/(2)/(8)/(10)/(11) |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------------+
```

I have procedures that update the `SomeValue` and `FullPath` values after, so don't worry about those! I'm interested in how to reproduce the hierarchy

Here is the code to insert sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentID INT,
    SomeValue VARCHAR(30),
    FullPath VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(NULL,'A','(1)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES('1','A.1','(1)/(2)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES('2','A.1.1','(1)/(2)/(3)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES(NULL,'B','(4)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES('4','B.1','(4)/(5)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES('4','B.2','(4)/(6)')
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES('6','B.2.1','(4)/(6)/(7)')
```

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns a scalar value which has the value of the last `IDENTITY` generated in the **prior** statement, it won't work in the context here. If you need to `INSERT` parent rows, and their children, you'll need to do each "level" separately.

Comment: Then, a `CURSOR` an inserting each row step by step would be the only way to do this ?

Comment: So each layer can only have 1 child and parent?

Comment: No, but I have access to the Hierarchical Path, so a simple `WHERE Path LIKE CONCAT('%/', @pkID, '%/')` should suffice to get all children

Comment: Sample `INSERT`/`UPDATE` data and expected result will help me help you here. I suspect you're going to need a couple of table variables.

Comment: Sample data is already in the question. I'll add the insert data, give me a couple minutes

Comment: If that's the sample data, why not just `INSERT` that then? You already have all the relevant IDs.

Comment: That's the sample data, but the case is I want to copy a branch into another. I will update the question, give me a couple minutes !

Comment: I added everything, tell me if I'm missing something

Comment: OK, you can do something like this, but it's somewhat messy. I'll try to get something to you later, but might be a couple hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218522/discussion-between-regularnormaldayguy-and-larnu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's not beat around the bush, this is pretty messy, and takes a couple of sweeps.

We need to first use a `MERGE` here (with no `UPDATE` clause) so that we can `OUTPUT` the new and old ID values into a table variable. Then, afterwards we need to use an `UPDATE` to update all the paths for the new path.

You could likely `UPDATE` the prior level in the `MERGE` and at  the same time `INSERT` the current level within the `MERGE,` however, I didn't go down that path, as it was potentially messier. Therefore, after inserting the rows, I use a further rCTe to create the new paths and `UPDATE` them.

This gives you the below (annotated) SQL:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Data
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentID INT,
    SomeValue VARCHAR(30),
    FullPath VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Data
--VALUES has supported multiple rows in 2008, you should be making use of it.
VALUES(NULL,'A','(1)')
     ,('1','A.1','(1)/(2)')
     ,('2','A.1.1','(1)/(2)/(3)')
     ,(NULL,'B','(4)')
     ,('4','B.1','(4)/(5)')
     ,('4','B.2','(4)/(6)')
     ,('6','B.2.1','(4)/(6)/(7)')
GO
--There are your parameters
DECLARE @BranchToCopy int,
        @CopysParent int;

SET @BranchToCopy = 4;
SET @CopysParent = 2;

--Table which will have the data to INSERT in
DECLARE @NewData table (ID int,
                        ParentID int,
                        SomeValue varchar(30),
                        FullPath varchar(255),
                        Level int);

--Will be used in the MERGE's OUTPUT clause to link the new and old IDs
DECLARE @Keys table (OldID int,
                     NewID int,
                     Level int);

--Get the hierachical data and INSERT into the @NewData variable
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT D.ID,
           D.ParentID,
           D.SomeValue,
           D.FullPath,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.Data D
    WHERE ID = @BranchToCopy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.ID,
           D.ParentID,
           D.SomeValue,
           D.FullPath,
           r.[Level] + 1
    FROM dbo.Data D
         JOIN rCTE r ON D.ParentID = r.ID)
INSERT INTO @NewData (ID,ParentID,SomeValue,FullPath,Level)
SELECT r.ID,
       r.ParentID,
       CONCAT(r.SomeValue,'-Copy'),
       r.FullPath,
       r.[Level]
FROM rCTE r;

--Uncomment to see results
--SELECT *
--FROM @NewData;

--Yes, we're using a WHILE!
--This, however, is what is known as a "set based loop"
DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i <= (SELECT MAX(Level) FROM @NewData) BEGIN

    --We use MERGE here as it allows us to OUTPUT columns that weren't inserted into the table
    MERGE INTO dbo.Data USING (SELECT ND.ID,
                                      CASE ND.ID WHEN @BranchToCopy THEN @CopysParent ELSE K.NewID END AS Parent,
                                      ND.SomeValue,
                                      ND.Level
                               FROM @NewData ND
                                    LEFT JOIN @Keys K ON ND.ParentID = K.OldID
                               WHERE ND.Level = @i) U ON 0=1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ParentID, SomeValue)
        VALUES (U.Parent, U.SomeValue)
        OUTPUT U.ID, inserted.ID, U.Level
        INTO @Keys (OldID, NewID, Level);

    --Increment
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

--Uncomment to see results
--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.[Data];

--Now we need to do the FullPath, as that would be a pain to do on the fly
DECLARE @Paths table (ID int, NewPath varchar(255));

--Work out the new paths
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT D.ID,
           D.ParentID,
           D.SomeValue,
           D.FullPath,
           CONVERT(varchar(255),NULL) AS NewPath
    FROM dbo.Data D
    WHERE D.ID = @CopysParent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.ID,
           D.ParentID,
           D.SomeValue,
           D.FullPath,
           CONVERT(varchar(255),CONCAT(ISNULL(r.FullPath,r.NewPath),'/(',D.ID,')'))
    FROM dbo.Data D
         JOIN rCTE r ON D.ParentID = r.ID
         JOIN @Keys K ON D.ID = K.NewID) --As we want only the new rows
INSERT INTO @Paths (ID, NewPath)
SELECT ID, NewPath
FROM rCTe
WHERE FullPath IS NULL;
--Update the table
UPDATE D
SET FullPath = P.NewPath
FROM dbo.Data D
     JOIN @Paths P ON D.ID = P.ID;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Data;

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.Data;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=177ca97548a01b42408bb100c6049fc5)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, using only CTE's:
The path `config as ( ...` defines the from and to ids to be used for the computation. This could all be done in a TVF.

```
WITH T AS (
select 1 id, null parentid, 'A'     somevalue, '(1)'         fullpath union all
select 2 id, 1    parentid, 'A.1'   somevalue, '(1)/(2)'     fullpath union all
select 3 id, 2    parentid, 'A.1.1' somevalue, '(1)/(2)/(3)' fullpath union all
select 4 id, NULL parentid, 'B'     somevalue, '(4)'         fullpath union all
select 5 id, 4    parentid, 'B.1'   somevalue, '(4)/(5)'     fullpath union all
select 6 id, 4    parentid, 'B.2'   somevalue, '(4)/(6)'     fullpath union all
select 7 id, 6    parentid, 'B.2.1' somevalue, '(4)/(6)/(7)' fullpath
)

, config as (
select 4 from_id, 2 to_id
)

, maxid as (
select max(id) maxid from t
)

, initpath as (
select fullpath from t cross join config where id = to_id
)

, subset_from as (
select t.*, maxid + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) new_id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn from t cross join config cross join maxid where fullpath like '(' + cast(from_id as varchar) + ')%'
)

, subset_count as (
select count(*) subset_count from subset_from
)

, fullpath_replacements (id, parentid, somevalue, new_id, fullpath, new_fullpath, lvl) as (
select id, parentid, somevalue, new_id, fullpath, replace(fullpath, '(' + cast((select sf.id from subset_from sf where rn = 1) as varchar) + ')', '(' + cast((select sf.new_id from subset_from sf where rn = 1) as varchar) + ')'), 1 
from subset_from

union all
select id, parentid, somevalue, new_id, fullpath, replace(new_fullpath, '(' + cast((select sf.id from subset_from sf where sf.rn = fr.lvl + 1) as varchar) + ')', '(' + cast((select sf.new_id from subset_from sf where sf.rn = fr.lvl + 1) as varchar) + ')'), fr.lvl + 1 
from fullpath_replacements fr where fr.lvl < (select subset_count from subset_count)
)

, final_replacement as (
select id, parentid, somevalue, new_id, fullpath, (select fullpath from t where t.id = (select to_id from config)) + '/' + new_fullpath new_fullpath, isnull((select sf.new_id from subset_from sf where sf.id = fr.parentid), (select to_id from config)) new_parentid
  from fullpath_replacements fr where fr.lvl = (select subset_count from subset_count)
)

select id, parentid, somevalue, fullpath 
from (
    select * from t
    union all
    select new_id, new_parentid, somevalue, new_fullpath from final_replacement
) t order by id
```

The idea is to create new ids with the row_number window function (see `subset_from` part).
Then make the replacements in the fullpath id by id. That is done using a recursive CTE `fullpath_replacements` to simulate a loop.

This works because in the fullpath I can always use the brackets to identify which part of the fullpath needs to be exchanged.

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually `INSERT` anything into the table though, so how do the values you generate in the CTE know what the values of the (yet to be created) `IDENTITY`  are going to be here?

Comment: If, for example, we simulate that (at least) there was one failed `INSERT` peviously, this doesn't work as expected. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d30e617e8214fecb0b45c7510cf63145)